# Firestore Rules file - unable to edit & save

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am following a tutorial (Firebase in Depth - Vasco) and have become stuck.

I was running my app in conjunction with the emulator and CRUD test data in the Cloud Firestore and everything was working fine. I closed down the emulator and have tried launching but the app is now presenting me with an error when it tries to CRUD the test data - "FirbaseError: false for 'list' @ L6". I am able to view the test data in the console and my app loads but I cannot see the test dat in my app.

I think it may be down to my security rules (below).

I am able to change and save the firebase rules in my console but these changes are not reflected in the firebase.rules file in my app. I try to directly change the file in the app (MAC OS) but a pop up tells me I don't have permissions. I just want to change the timestamp date, which I think will resolve the issue but can't edit and save.

firebase.rules file in app

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 6, 4);
    }
  }
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Hi @Robgit28, Just to confirm, are you using AngularFire?

Comment: Yes it's AngularFire

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the file was corrupted so had to create a duplicate file with a new name (i.e. firebase1.rules), then delete the old file (firebase.rules) and finally rename the new file with the original name (i.e. firebase.rules).